# Find repeated words, first occurrence only

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following block of text:

```
Hi, here
is some text. 
This is some Hi here more
And some.
```

I would like to highlight items with multiple words, like this:

- [`(?=\b([a-z]{2,})\b.*\b\1\b)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/WPK7Ja/2)

[image]

However, I only want it to highlight the first match -- in other words the word shouldn't have a match before it (the second `some` shouldn't show up). The only way I can think to do this is using a negative lookbehind, but I'm using python's regex which doesn't allow variable-length lookbehinds. How could this be done?

---

And yes, of course I can do something like the following:

```
>>> from collections import Counter;Counter('Hi, here\nis some text. \nThis is some Hi here more\nAnd some.'.split())
Counter({'some': 2, 'is': 2, 'here': 2, 'And': 1, 'This': 1, 'text.': 1, 'some.': 1, 'Hi': 1, 'Hi,': 1, 'more': 1})
```

But I'm curious if it's possible to do this with a **regex**.

Comment: Do `pip install regex` and enjoy unlimited length lookbehind patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ha, ok I'll try that. Is there a way to do this without a lookbehind?

Comment: Just `list(set(result))`. This task is always better done with regex+additional code.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use regex for this? There could be simpler methods.

Comment: What is an "item"? A line?

Comment: @Victor a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task that is always better done with a combination of regex and code:

```py
import re
text = 'Hi, here\nis some text. \nThis is some Hi here more\nAnd some.'
print( list(set(re.findall(r'\b([a-z]{2,})\b(?=.*\b\1\b)', text, re.DOTALL))) )
# => ['here', 'some', 'is']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Y6H7f2).

If you have some very specific task only involving a single regex operation, you need to install the [PyPi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (type `pip install regex` or `pip3 intall regex` in the terminal and hit ENTER) and use

```py
import regex
text = r'''Hi, here
is some text. 
This is some Hi here more
And some.'''
print( regex.findall(r'\b([a-z]{2,})\b(?<!\b\1\b.*\1)(?=.*\b\1\b)', text, regex.DOTALL) )
# => ['here', 'some', 'is']
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##NY0xD8IgFIR3fsVzAgySVFebpkmHDk1cuolDm6KQtNBQhqrxtyOiTpf73t29@e6VNYcQ9DRb58HJm1yRl6uHHBzGuNYMlHQS6QUWO0n43DigVkXwZ7VOGZhsDJZmSJTHNpqdNp58Z/lVm6EbR@Kw6Mm52z0uzz170WiK40b0IhM934qMkiKPmjzFLH1kv4nq1JZNQ4GG8AY) and [this ECMAScript regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vp0jsB/1). The `(?<!\b\1\b.*\1)` lookbehind fails the match if the word captured into Group 1 appears *anywhere before* this match.

Note your regex does not assume there can be overlapping matches since it only matches whole words composed of two or more lowercase ASCII letters, hence, I removed the capturing group and the outer lookahead.